# Parse tabular output from Subprocess Check_Output

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm working on a Python(3.6) project in which I need to parse data from a tabular output of subprocess.check_output.

Here's How I'm using this:
The output is:

```
NAME      HOSTS     ADDRESS           PORTS     AGE
mysvcs    *         107.178.250.150   80        1m
```

This out loads an empty column for ADDRESS like this:

```
NAME      HOSTS     ADDRESS           PORTS     AGE
mysvcs    *                           80        1m
```

But after few moments it loads the `107.178.250.150` in the 3rd column of second row.
So, how can I get this `address` when it has been populated.
Here's how I'm trying:

```
address = subprocess.check_output(["kubectl get ing | awk '{print $3}'"], shell=True)
            all_address = out_ip.decode().split('\n')
            print(all_address)
            address = all_address[1]
            print(address)
            if not address:
                while address == '':
                    out_address = subprocess.check_output(["kubectl get ing | awk '{print $3}'"], shell=True)
                    all_address = out_ip.decode().split('\n')
                    ip = all_address[1]
                    print(address)
```

But it's even not running the while loop and output as:

> **`b'ADDRESS\n80\n'
>   ['ADDRESS', '80', '']
>   80`**

---

> **Update:** Here's how I have tried stovfl's answer:

```
            ip = ''
            # Limit to 5 loops
            for n in range(5):
                result = subprocess.check_output(["kubectl get ing | awk '{print $3}'"], shell=True)
                # Make a List from the result, spliting at NewLine
                _list = result.decode().split('\n')

                # Check if Value 2 (Index==1) matches a IP Address
                if re.match(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', _list[1]):
                    ip = _list[1]
                    print("match:{}".format(_list[1]))
                    # End the loop
                    break

                # Wait a second, before next try
                time.sleep(1)

                address = 'http://' + ip
```

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(address)`

Comment: Hi @stovfl, it's output is `80` outside the while loop.

Comment: I want to see it, right after `subprocess.check_output(...`

Comment: Hi @stovfl, if the address has been created then it's output is: `ADDRESS\n35.241.40.83\n` but if it's not created then output is `ADDRESS\n80\n`

Comment: So you simple want to `loop` until you get a IP Address?

Comment: yes, exactly, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: Parse tabular output, loop until results a IP Address

```
import time, re

# Limit to 5 loops
for n in range(5):
    result = subprocess.check_output(["kubectl get ing | awk '{print $3}'"], shell=True)
     # Make a List from the result, spliting at NewLine
    _list = result.decode().split('\n')
    # DEBUG
    print("list:{}".format(_list))

    # Check if Value 2 (Index==1) matches a IP Address
    if re.match(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', _list[1]):
        print("match:{}".format(_list[1]))
        # End the loop
        break

    # Wait a second, before next try
    time.sleep(1)
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Hi @stovfl, it's not working, it's still not printing the `match`.

Comment: Now it's output is: `list:['ADDRESS', '80', '']
list:['ADDRESS', '80', '']
list:['ADDRESS', '80', '']
list:['ADDRESS', '80', '']
list:['ADDRESS', '80', '']`

Comment: @AbdulRehman: You got **no** IP Address, raise delay to `time.sleep(3)`. How could you be safe `kubectl` will return a IP Address?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.5 or newer, you can upgrade to `subprocess.run()` which has some useful features.

I would also factor out the shell and the Awk pipeline.

```
addr = None
while True:
    result = subprocess.run(
        ['kubectl', 'get', 'ing'],
        stdout=subprocess,PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True, check=True)
    lines = result.stdout.split('\n')
    # [1:] - skip header line
    # [:-1] - skip empty element after last newline
    for line in lines[1:-1]:
        # replace Awk
        filelds = line.split()
        if len(fields) > 2 and '.' in fields[2]:
            addr = fields[2]
            break
    if addr:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

The `text=True` takes care of automatically normalizing the output to Unicode with standard line breaks. (Before Python 3.7 this was `universal_newlines=True`.)

Comment: Hi @tripleee, TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Comment: @AbdulRehman `text` was renamed in 3.7; the older, slightly misleading name was `universal_newlines`. Again, see the linked answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution for Python(3.6):

```
addr = None
while addr is None:
     out = subprocess.check_output(["kubectl get ing | awk '{print $3}'"], shell=True)
     print(out)
     all_addr = out.decode().split('\n')
     if re.match(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", str(all_addr[1])):
         addr = all_addr[1]
         print('Address is: {}'.format(addr))
     else:
         addr = None
```